# 'Ahí hay un auto' duda sobre construcciones sintácticas

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, orden-de-palabras

En base a una pregunta reciente que vi, relacionada al uso de las palabras *hay* y *allí*, intenté imaginar todos los posibles usos que podrían tener ambas estando juntas en una oración. Al cabo de un momento, pensé algo un poco más interesante: ¿Qué pasaría si usara *hay* junto con *ahí* en una frase? Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue algo como 'ahí hay un auto'. Entonces intenté probar todas las posibles permutaciones entre los sintagmas 'ahí', 'hay' y 'un auto' para ver cuales frases resultaban sintáticamente correctas:

> Ahí hay un auto.

> Ahí un auto hay.

> Hay un auto ahí.

> Hay ahí un auto.

> Un auto ahí hay.

> Un auto hay ahí.

¡Pero no pude descartar ninguna como sintácticamente incorrecta! Aclaro que me refiero al punto de vista *sintáctico* porque todas las frases me parecen cacofónicas—sobre todo las últimas dos, que nunca las emplearía. De todas formas ¿alguien es capaz de esclarecerme la duda sobre si las oraciones son correctas? De ser cierto ¿A alguien se le ocurre algún(os) otro(s) ejemplo(s) sencillo(s) y similar(es) en donde la inversión no sea válida?

Comment: "Un auto ahí hay" no me parece una oración correcta.

Comment: @Gustavson sí es correcta, aunque no se use normalmente. Ejemplo de conversación: - A: compra chocolate. - B (señalando): Chocolate ahí hay, no voy a comprar más.

Comment: @Gustavson Creo que todas son correctas, algunas raras sí, pero correctas al fin, es que las dos últimas tienen un orden opuesto a lo que acostumbramos hoy en día. Por ejemplo, es correcto "el León feroz es," más allá de que sólo vemos esas cosas en letras de canciones o literatura de la de antes.